# Find a deleted number from a list

Tags: python

Considering two lists (a sequence of numbers from 1 to N (arr) and the same sequence mixed but missing one number (mixed_arr)). The goal is to find the number that was deleted.

Example:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
mixed_arr = [3,4,1,5]
```

The output should be 2.

Return 0 if no number was deleted and if there is no difference 
If no number was deleted from the array and no difference with it, the function has to return 0. Note that N may be 1 or less (in the latter case, the first array will be []).

Testcases:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
mixed_arr = [1,9,7,4,6,2,3,8]
output = 5

arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
mixed_arr = [5,7,6,9,4,8,1,2,3]
output = 0
```

Here's my code:

```
def find_deleted_number(arr, mixed_arr):
    arr.sort()
    mixed_arr.sort()

    for x in range(arr):
        for y in range(mixed_arr):
            if arr[x] != mixed_arr[y]:
                return arr[x]
            elif arr[x] == mixed_arr[y]:
                return 0
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback:
   in <module>
   in find_deleted_number
TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: remove the range in `for x in range(arr):` and `for x in range(mixed_arr):` and no need to call `arr[x]`, just `x`

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying to pass an list object to the `range()` function. But since `range()` only accepts integers, Python complains.

Comment: In addition to removing range(), you'll find that x and y will become the values in the arrays, not the indices.

Comment: Also you cannot index into a list like `arr[x]`. `x` is already a member, not the index. Just use `x`.

Comment: As a side note, there is a much simpler solution for this without nested `for` loops. Simply sum the whole range and the sum of the given list, then subtract the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use `symmetric_difference()`, a member of `set`:

```py
set(arr).symmetric_difference(mixed_arr)
```

See also [sets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).

Please note, as pointed out by DeepSpace in the comments, if it is guaranteed that both lists contain integers from 1 to N, with the exception of one missing in one of those lists, the much more efficient solution is to compute the absolute value of the difference of the sum of both lists:

```
abs(sum(arr) - sum(mixed_arr))
```

---

**The error you're getting:**

You're getting the error because of this line:

```
for x in range(arr): # arr is a list, not an int
```

You surely intended to pass the length of the array:

```
for x in range(len(arr)):
```

The same goes for the inner loop.

Answer (score 3):

Why not to use `set`?

```
>>> arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> mixed_arr = [1,9,7,4,6,2,3,8]
>>> list(set(arr) - set(mixed_arr))
[5]
```

This *general solution* will handle arrays with no constraints on integers, or on the size of lists (or the size of the difference).

**Edit.** In your (very) specific case with **positive integers**, and **only one missing** in the other array, it's much more efficient to use the solution from comments below:

```
>>> abs(sum(arr) - sum(mixed_arr))
5
```

Comment: While this gives the correct result, you can simply return the difference of the sums of the two arrays since by definition each have unique elements.

Comment: @DeepSpace absolute value of the difference.

Comment: You're absolutely right, in this particular case, that's much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to pass an list object to the `range()` function. But since `range()` only accepts integers, Python complains. You are also making the same mistake with `mixed_arr`.

But there are easier ways to accomplish this. In this case, you can use `set()`s to find the difference between two lists:

```
>>> set([1,2,3,4,5]) - set([3,4,1,5])
{2}
>>>
```

Or this could be done using a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> mixed_arr = [3,4,1,5]
>>> 
>>> [el for el in arr if el not in mixed_arr]
[2]
>>>
```